# XSL storing node list in a variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to store the following list in xml into a variable

```html
<Locations>
  <Location>A1</Location>
  <Location>A2</Location>
  <Location>A3</Location>
  <Location>C1</Location>
  <Location>C2</Location>
</Locations>
```

this is my xsl code

```html
<xsl:variable name="my_locations" select="*/text()"/>
```

I verified that `*/text()` contains all the string location values via visual studio debugger

but `my_locations` still seems to be empty

I have to use xsl stylesheet version 1.0 for my task

please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath `*/text()`, because it doesn't start with a `/`, is evaluated relative to a "context node" (i.e. a current node). Depending on where your `xsl:variable` statement that context node could be anything. You should really have provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), for your question.

Let's assume that the `xsl:variable` is a child element of the `xsl:stylesheet`; in that case, typically the context node is the document node of the input document, and the path will return text nodes which are children of the root element, as if your XPath were `/*/text()`. However, the text nodes you are after are not children of the root element; they are children of the child elements of the root element.

Try this instead:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="my_locations" select="/Locations/Location/text()"/>
```

or just

```xml
<xsl:variable name="my_locations" select="//Location/text()"/>
```